# How can I implement a Deterministic finite automaton which accepts strings having specific words.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, automata

I am trying to make a [Deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) which accepts those strings having two 
specific words(either one) anywhere as a substring. The problem is really simple if the characters of the words do not match, on the contrary if the characters of these two words match somewhere, then I don't see any way out.

For instance how can I implement a DFA which accepts those strings having $100$ or $110$ as substring anywhere?

Comment: Can you build a NFA (non deterministic) accepting the language you want ? You can then determinise it.

Comment: @KevinQuirin No I couldn't, can you help with the example?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a NFA accepting your language, where I the an initial state, and F is a final state.

[image: Nondeterministic Finite Automata]

It reads the word, and, in a non-deterministic way, choses to read one of the subword you want.

Then, you "just" have to [determinise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#/Equivalence_to_DFA) it (be careful, it can have up to $2^8$ states… you may want to rewrite the NFA with less states)

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=(Q,\Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$ where the set of states is
$$Q=\{q_0, q_1, q_{11}, q_{10}, q_f\}, $$
the input alphabet is $$\Sigma = \{0,1\}, $$
the transition function $\delta: Q\times \Sigma\to\ Q$ is defined by
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\delta(q,b)& q_0 & q_1 & q_{11} & q_{10} & q_f\\\hline
0 & q_0 &  q_{10} & q_f & q_f & q_f \\
1 & q_1 & q_{11} & q_{11} & q_1 & q_f
\end{array}

[image]

$q_0$ is the start state, and $F=\{q_f\}$ is the set of accepting states. Then the language of $M$ is
$$(0\cup 1)^*(100)\cup(110)\cup(0,1)^*, $$
as desired.

Comment: @Kevin Quirin Thanks for adding the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

1. Build a DFA $A_1$ that accepts strings with $100$.
2. Build a DFA $A_2$ that accepts strings with $110$.
3. Build DFA $A$ that accepts strings with $100$ **or** $110$. The latter is the *union* of DFA's $A_1$ and $A_2$ (the union accepts a string iff it is accepted by $A_1$ or $A_2$). Here [ [link](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs235/fall09/lectures/14_DFA_operations/14_DFA_operations_revised.pdf) ] (pp.3-5) you can find some example how to perform this operation.

P.S.: If you need a DFA that accepts a string iff it is accepted by $A_1$ **and** $A_2$ you can use the *intersection* of DFA's.